# RavenDB dynamic objects

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have code that looks something like this:

```
using (var session = DocumentStore.OpenSession())
{
    var dbItem = session.Load<dynamic>(item.Id);    
    if (dbItem is DynamicJsonObject)
    {
        dbItem["PropertyName"] = "new value";
    }
    session.SaveChanges();
}
```

What I can't figure out is how to update properties of the dbItem.
Does anyone know what to do?
I have tried accessing the property name directly like this:
dbItem.PropertyName
I have also tried casting to ExpandoObject, IDictionary and more. But nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Raven 2.5, the support for dynamic objects seems to be mostly for the read side of things, and it's not that easy to set properties on an existing object because `Raven.Abstractions.Linq.DynamicJsonObject`, which inherits `DynamicObject`, only implements the read/invoke methods of the dynamic contract, like `TryGetMember`, `TryGetIndex`, and `TryInvokeMember`. but none of the items like `TrySetMember`.

However, if you cast to `IDynamicJsonObject` it provides access to the inner `RavenJObject` which you can manipulate.

This code sample should illustrate how:

```
using (var session = store.OpenSession())
{
    dynamic entity = new ExpandoObject();
    entity.Id = "DynamicObjects/1";
    entity.Hello = "World";
    session.Store(entity);
    session.SaveChanges();
}

using (var session = store.OpenSession())
{
    var json = session.Load<dynamic>("DynamicObjects/1") as IDynamicJsonObject;
    json.Inner["Name"] = "Lionel Ritchie";
    json.Inner["Hello"] = "Is it me you're looking for?";
    session.SaveChanges();
}

using (var session = store.OpenSession())
{
    dynamic loadedAgain = session.Load<dynamic>("DynamicObjects/1");
    Console.WriteLine("{0} says Hello, {1}", loadedAgain.Name, loadedAgain.Hello);
    // -> Lionel Ritchie says Hello, Is it me you're looking for?"
}
```

Comment: Very simple solution. I tried many ways to get to this 'inner' object. Didn't know just casting to IDynamicJsonObject would do the trick, thanks.