# How to store C# objects with dynamic properties in RavenDB?

Tags: c#, ravendb

I'm having problems when trying to save an object that has a dynamic property in RavenDB

The object I'm trying to save represents an order. The order contains a list of orderlines so imagine the following Order class:

```
public class Order {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Orderline> Orderlines { get; set; }
}
```

And the Orderline class being:

```
public class Orderline {
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public dynamic Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

The object I'm trying to save (I'll display it with JSON);

```
{
    "Id": 0,
    "Orderlines": [
        {
            "Product": {
                "Id": 0,
                "Name": "Some product"
            },
            "Quantity": 1,
            "Attributes": {
                "color": "Red"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Saving it does not throw any errors
RavenDB stores the Order object as

```
{
    "Id": 0,
    "Orderlines": [
        {
            "Product": {
                "Id": 0,
                "Name": "Some product"
            },
            "Quantity": 1,
            "Attributes": {
                "$type": "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject, Newtonsoft.Json",
                "color": {
                    "$type": "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue, Newtonsoft.Json",
                    "$values": []
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that the values property of `Order.Orderlines[0].Attributes.color` is not set...

When I try to serialize the object back to my C# Order object I get the following exception;

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.CollectionWrapper`1[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken]'
>   to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue'.

What am I doing wrong, how can I store this object in the RavenDB database and retrieve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208510/ravendb-dynamic-objects may be relevant

Comment: Why do you need the dynamic? Is the solution, don't use dynamics

Comment: @Liam The thing is, I'm trying to have a generic Orderline object that can still contain custom properties. This is relevant because in the future, I'd like to have multiple products use the same API that can store the application-specific custom-attributes in the Attributes property (in this case color)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing the dynamic property with type 'dynamic' apparently wasn't enough. When I gave the Attributes property the ExpandoObject type, RavenDB stored the Attributes property as normal JSON (without $type and $values, so clean as desired)

When retrieving it back from the RavenDB database it deserializes back to an ExpandoObject object.

Make sure to cast the ExpandoObject property to a dynamic (e.g. 'as dynamic') when trying to display the property in a Razor view.

Answer (score 2):

What is the type that you are actually saving into attributes?
Typically you'll use something that is actually dynamic, like ExpandoObject